# Проблема при изменении заголовка в диспетчере задач

Tags: c#, .net

Собственно смесь UIAutomation и p\invoke:

```
internal class UIAutomation
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        internal static void SetTextToHeaderTaskManager(string text)
        {
            // Get process Task Manager
            var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("taskmgr");

            // Get window
            var window = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc[0].MainWindowHandle);

            // Set focus
            window.SetFocus();

            // Get header class
            var taskHeader = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "TaskManagerWindow", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase);

            // Get UI element
            var headerElement = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, taskHeader);

            // Set text to header 
            SendMessage(headerElement.Current.NativeWindowHandle, 0x000C, Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(text), IntPtr.Zero);
        }
```

Суть проблемы: текст из заголовка диспетчера задач пропадает, но текст, отправленный через SendMessage - не появляется. В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была в перепутанных параметрах функции SendMessage, вот причесанный готовый вариант:

```
internal class UIAutomation
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        internal static void SetTextToHeaderTaskManager(string text)
        {
            // Get or run process Task Manager
            var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("taskmgr");
            if (proc == null || proc.Length <= 0)
            {
                var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                info.FileName = "taskmgr";
                info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                info.UseShellExecute = false;
                info.Verb = "runas";
                proc = new Process[1]{ Process.Start(info) };
            }

            // Get window
            var window = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc[0].MainWindowHandle);
            if (window == null)
                throw new Exception("Window not found");

            // Set focus
            window.SetFocus();

            // Get header class
            var taskHeader = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "TaskManagerWindow", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase);

            // Get UI element
            var headerElement = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, taskHeader);
            if (headerElement == null)
                throw new Exception("Header class not found");

            // Set text to header
            SendMessage(headerElement.Current.NativeWindowHandle, 0x000C, IntPtr.Zero, Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(text));
        }
    }
```